# TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)

Tags: openvpn

**Hi Everyone, i try connect with VPN server by using windows connected but when try connect with mobile android by using mobile app (openvpn for android) not connected and it give me this error on vpn server log.**

*`TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)`*

Answer (score 0):

Connect windows OR the android phone... can't connect 2 devices on same time with same user. you can use the same user for different devices but only one at time.